# SQlite how to display employee and manager names in this table?

Tags: sqlite

I am new to SQLite. I want to display the name of each employee and his/her manager's name. But I am a little confused about how to link the managerID with EmployeeID? Do I need to use subquery?

```
table: Employee
Columns: EmployeeID [pk], EmployeeName, ManagerID
```

Like:

```
EmployeeID    EmployeeName   ManagerID
  1              Alice          2
  2              Peter         null
  3              John           2
  4              Mary           1
```

means Peter is Alice and John's manager and Alice is Mary's manager.

```
SELECT EmployeeName AS Employee, EmployeeName AS Manager
FROM Employee
WHERE
```

Comment: Look into JOINs. Lots of information out there to get a basic idea about how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the table on itself with a [LEFT OUTER join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp). Since the boss won't have a manager (null), use '[ifnull](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull)':

```
select A.EmployeeName as 'EmployeeName', 
   ifnull(B.EmployeeName, 'BOSS') as 'ManagerName' 
   from employee A left outer join employee B 
   on A.managerId = B.employeeId;
```